# N2CMS - Firefox 30 : Part selector drag&drop broken

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop, n2

I'm currently using the N2 CMS framework (version 2.6.3) for my Asp website, and since the last firefox update (30.0) the part selector doen't work anymore.

When editing a page, the part selector his partly outside of the screen and the drag and drop doesn't work at all.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was just a side effect coming from an obsolete version of jquery. 

Problem solved!